# Using setTimeout() to mutate state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got the following React code. When `order.ordStatus` becomes `canceled`, I want to remove that `order` from the array `state.orders` after 10 seconds.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to refer to `state` inside my `setTimeout()`. (I tried `useRef` as I've left it in, but this doesn't work).

Even a suggestion of the right way to go might be enough!

Thank you all! :)

```
const ActiveOrders = () => {
  let currentUser = userService.currentUser;
  const stateRef = useRef(state);

  const state = useChannel(`order:${currentUser.account_id}`, ordersReducer, {
    orders: [],
  });

  return (
      <tbody>{state.orders.map(orderRow)}</tbody>
  );
};

function ordersReducer(state, { event, payload }) {
  const cleanUpOrder = orderId => {
    let orders = ActiveOrders.stateRef.current.orders;
    let updatedOrders = remove(orders, o => o.orderId === orderId);
    return { ...state, orders: updatedOrders };
  };
  switch (event) {
    case 'upsert':
      let updatedOrders = upsertOrder(state.orders, payload);
      if (['canceled', 'filled'].includes(payload.ordStatus)) {
        setTimeout(cleanUpOrder, 1000, payload.orderId);
      }
      return { ...state, orders: updatedOrders };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to useRef that makes sense see https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: What is useChannel? And is it possible to make the event asynchronous instead of the reducer?

Comment: useChannel is a context provider that provides a websocket subscription to the component. I'm not sure how to do it any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the setTimeout and clearTimeout inside useEffect hook.

Even better way would be using useTimeout custom hook. There are some readymade you can install via NPM, or a few tutorials if you want to roll your own.

E.g. https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/usetime-react-hook-f57979338de

Something like:

```
const [state, setState]= useState();
const removeOrder = ()=> setState('empty');

useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (state === 'canceled') {
       timer = setTimeout(removeOrder, 4000);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [state, removeOrder]);
```

Comment: How does setTimeout() have access to the current state when called from useEffect? As I understand it, it will suffer from the same issue, no matter where I call it?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Ohh, you are using timeout inside reducer. Don't do that, it makes the reducer not pure (not deterministic). Put the timeout in custom redux middleware or actioncreator instead.

Comment: NMP? Do you mean NPM?